# Linking stepper to Slider UIObject in C4

Tags: uislider, uistepper, c4

I am very new to C4 so please be gentle...

If I want to link a slider value to a label this is done with NSString stringWithFormat... e.g.:

```
self.mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",slider.value];
```

I added a stepper object as well, and now it also updates mylabel:

```
self.mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",stepper.value];
```

But it would be intuitive if the slider position follows the label value when I'm using the stepper. but `.value` is not an available property in `UILabel`... so how do I take the `mylabel.text` property and push that into the `slider.value` property without getting a datatype mismatch error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has 2 answers, how to do it using C4 objects and how to do it with Interface Builder / UIControls. I'll show both ways, UI first so that I can compare the C4 way afterwards.

**UIControl**

---

To do this with UIControls first set up your `C4WorkSpace.h` header so that it has the following methods and properties:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *myStepper;

-(IBAction)sliderWasUpdated:(UISlider *)slider;
-(IBAction)stepperWasUpdated:(UIStepper *)stepper;
```

Then, in your drag all three components onto your projects XIB file (i.e. a UISlider, UILabel and UIStepper). Link the action `sliderWasUpdated:` to the slider using the `valueChanged` option, and the `stepperWasUpdated:` action to the stepper also using the `valueChanged` option. You do this step by selecting `C4Canvas.xib` from your project then right-clicking on the yellow cube, then dragging from the actions listed in the pop-up menu to each of the objects that you recently placed on the canvas.

Next, add the following code to your `C4WorkSpace.m` file:

```
@implementation C4WorkSpace

-(void)setup {
    self.myStepper.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.myStepper.maximumValue = 10.0f;

    self.mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.mySlider.maximumValue = 10.0f;
}

-(IBAction)sliderWasUpdated:(UISlider *)slider {
    slider.value = [C4Math round:slider.value];
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",slider.value];
    self.myStepper.value = slider.value;
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
}

-(IBAction)stepperWasUpdated:(UIStepper *)stepper {
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",stepper.value];
    self.mySlider.value = stepper.value;
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
}

@end
```

In the `setup` we make sure that the min/max values of both UI objects are the same (so that we can keep them matched up).

In the `stepperWasChanged:` method we do two things:

1. We use the stepper's value to set the label's text
2. We also use the stepper's value to set the slider's value!

In the `sliderWasChanged:` method we do the same thing, updating the stepper, but we also round the value of the slider so that it increments in steps (just to keep things tidy).

**C4Control**

---

To do the same with C4 objects, instead of native UI objects, we set things up a little differently. First, we don't add anything to our `C4Canvas.xib`, instead we'll set the objects up manually.

In your `C4WorkSpace.h` file, add the following lines of code:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) C4Label *myLabel;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) C4Slider *mySlider;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) C4Stepper *myStepper;

-(void)sliderWasUpdated:(C4Slider *)slider;
-(void)stepperWasUpdated:(C4Stepper *)stepper;
```

Notice that most of this is the same except we're using C4 instead of UI prefixes. Also, we call our methods `-(void)` instead of `-(IBAction)` because we're not using Interface Builder.

Next, add the following code to your `C4WorkSpace.m`:

```
@implementation C4WorkSpace

-(void)setup {
    [self createAddObjects];
    //calibrate the min/max values
    self.myStepper.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.myStepper.maximumValue = 10.0f;

    self.mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.mySlider.maximumValue = 10.0f;
}

-(void)sliderWasUpdated:(C4Slider *)slider {
    slider.value = [C4Math round:slider.value];
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",slider.value];
    self.myStepper.value = slider.value;
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
}

-(void)stepperWasUpdated:(C4Stepper *)stepper {
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f",stepper.value];
    self.mySlider.value = stepper.value;
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
}

-(void)createAddObjects {
    //set up the objects
    self.myLabel = [C4Label labelWithText:@"values"];
    self.myStepper = [C4Stepper stepper];
    self.mySlider = [C4Slider slider:CGRectMake(0, 0, 192, 44)];

    //position them
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.canvas.center.x,
                                      self.canvas.center.y - 100);
    self.myStepper.center = centerPoint;

    centerPoint.y += 100;
    self.myLabel.center = self.canvas.center;

    centerPoint.y += 100;
    self.mySlider.center = centerPoint;

    //set up action bindings
    [self.mySlider runMethod:@"sliderWasUpdated:"
                      target:self
                    forEvent:VALUECHANGED];
    [self.myStepper runMethod:@"stepperWasUpdated:"
                       target:self
                     forEvent:VALUECHANGED];

    [self.canvas addObjects:@[self.myStepper,self.myLabel,self.mySlider]];
}

@end
```

**DIFFERENCES**

---

The major difference between the two approaches is whether or not you use Interface Builder. In the C4 approach we need to add a method called `createAddObjects` to our project so that our slider, label and stepper all get added to the canvas.

This method also contains the methods for binding the actions of our C4UIElements to our code, which happens in the lines:

```
[self.mySlider runMethod:@"sliderWasUpdated:"
                  target:self
                forEvent:VALUECHANGED];
[self.myStepper runMethod:@"stepperWasUpdated:"
                   target:self
                 forEvent:VALUECHANGED];
```

Once these are set up the **only** difference is specifying the use of C4 objects instead of UI objects, like:

```
-(void)sliderWasUpdated:(C4Slider *)slider {...}
```

instead of

```
-(IBAction)sliderWasUpdated:(UISlider *)slider {...}
```

Comment: P.S. Here's a link to a gist with the code for the C4 approach: https://gist.github.com/C4Code/5614798

Comment: I guess I gravitate tot he UI Builder because in my work, I design touch screens which are based around a graphical, Drag 'n' Drop interface, which are usually just linked to a controller (PLC) via the address of a register in the controller. Typically I only write code to script very complex actions not dealt with in the user interface out-of-the box... ie parsing a text file and extracting specific pieces of data, or changing the way an onscreen element works. If you google a product like "Wonderware" or "RSView" you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: This is a little more daunting because I have to go back to my Visual Basic and C training to remember how basic things like declaring global variable works! C4 does make it quite easy to code very complex stuff on iOS though, so I'm really enjoying this!

Comment: Oh yeah, Interface Builder is what you want to learn then. I am looking forward to creating IB elements for C4 objects, so that you can drag them on to the canvas yourself. This might take a while though... Lots of plans, and only 10 fingers to make it all happen at the moment.